# Column with Non Clustered Index takes longer to Execute

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm trying to understand how to properly use nonclustered indexes. Here what I found with test data.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
    RowID int Not Null IDENTITY (1,1),
    Continent nvarchar(100),
    Location nvarchar(100)

    CONSTRAINT PK_TestTable_RowID 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RowID)
)

ALTER TABLE TestTable
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TestTable_RowID
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable
    SELECT Continent, Location
    FROM StgCovid19

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

SELECT *
FROM TestTable 
WHERE Continent = 'Asia' --551ms

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIContinent 
ON TestTable(Continent)

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE Continent = 'Asia' --1083ms

DROP INDEX NCIContinent
ON TestTable

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIContinent 
ON TestTable(Continent)
INCLUDE (Location)

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE Continent = 'Asia' ---530ms
```

As you guys can see, if I only add the non clustered index on the `Continent` column, it performs a seek and also takes double the time to execute the select.

[image]

When I add the `INCLUDE (Location)` it takes less than without any clustered index.

[image]

Are you guys able to tell me what is going on?

Comment: It's because of the `select *` in your query. It needs to lookup all of the columns in matching rows to satisfy the query. Read through [Clustered and Nonclustered Indexes Described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described) to understand how nonclustered indexes behave in the absence/presence of a clustered index - pay attention to the definition of "row locator."

Comment: Designing databases is a skill that must be learned. You dropped your primary key (and clustered index) immediately after creating the table - why? Doing that makes your table a heap. And if your columns are nvarchar, your literals should be as well. Develop good habits. Perhaps here you don't really need/intend nvarchar strings - but you created the table so you need to align your code with your schema.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Is it correct then, when I have queries that have where clauses on 'RowID' and 'Continent', I should have a clustered for 'RowID' (Primary Key) and Nonclustered for 'Continent'. If on my SELECT statement I also select the Country column, I should use INCLUDE on the nonclustered?

Comment: @SMor I'm learning data warehousing ETL and I was told that I should drop the indexes before inserting data to a table. Then create the index again after the insert. If the above was a real scenario, I'd not have create any index in the first place. I'd insert all data and the create the indexes

Answer (score 0):

The strategy of accessing data depends on the table structure, but also, and mainly, on data distribution. It is why statistics about data distribution are stored in indexes and tables :

- In indexes, to know the distribution (histogram) of the key value
- In tables, to  know the distribution (histogram) of the columns values

An execution plan is computed to create a tree compound of branches containing chained steps that are algorithms specialized in one action (join, sort, data access...) to construct the program that will retrieve the data in response to your demand (query).

The optimizer role is to determine, among many execution plans, which will be the most interresting, using the least resources (memory, data volume, cpu...). The plan choose is not systematycally the quicker one, but the one that will have the lower cost in terms in resources usage... This estimate is done by the optimizer upon the bias of statistics...

The test you make has no sense because we does not know the data distribution and the use of the DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS has a heavy slide effect that is not current in real word of databases exploitation. In real world, 98 % of the data used by users are in cache... !

Also mesuring time of execution of a query has two problematics :

- this metric is not stable and depends of the PC activity which is
  really heavy even when you do nothing. Usually we restart the test
  at least 10 time, eliminating the slowest and the quickest time and
  finally computing the average on the remaining 8 results
- time is not the only figure that is interresting and can be mostly the time to send resulting data to the client application. To eliminate this
  time, SSMS has a parameter that can execute the query without
  sghowing the resulting dataset in SSMS